# Regular expression to match (C) function calls

Tags: regex

Does anyone have a regular expression for matching function calls in C programs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more searching I decided to let the compiler do the hard work.

Get the compiler to produce a [Register Transfer Language (RTL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_Transfer_Language#RTL_in_GCC) file using the -dr options of gcc.

The produced RTL file has the suffix .rtl or .expand.

This file is far easier to parse as the functions calls are already identified.

Answer (score 3):

Since C isn't a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and C function calls can contain arbitrary argument expressions, I fear the answer to your question is “no.”

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can find a regex that matches all (and only) the function calls in some source code.  But maybe you could use a tool like [Understand](http://www.scitools.com/products/understand/), or your IDE, to browse your code.